# What is difference between scattering matrix method and transfer matrix method?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, scattering, definition

I want to simulate light propagation into nanostructures, but I do not know which method should I use: Scattering method or Transfer method?

Comment: This might be useful, https://github.com/qpv-research-group/rayflare

Answer (score -2):

If you simulate something with gain or losses use the scattering matrix, otherwise the transfer matrix

Comment: thank you for your comment, but would you please explain it more? what is the effect of losses or gain in the structure?